# Cannot compile R packages under Conda

Tags: r, anaconda, clang, conda, macos-catalina

OK, this is driving me crazy. 
I'm attempting to use Conda as a quasi-package manager for R on my Mac (OS 10.15) as I have done (successfully) on other Unix installations.

Repeatedly, the error I get is the following

Before the creation of a new conda environment, we have:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and

```
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

We create a new empty environment and check again

```
$ conda create --name r_env
$ conda activate r_env
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

Great. So far so good.
Now we install R and check again.

```
$ conda install r=3.6
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ which clang
/Users/dgarfield/miniconda3/envs/r_env/bin/clang
$ clang -v 
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/dgarfield/miniconda3/envs/r_env/bin
```

It appears that we have a new clang!
Why is this a problem?

```
$ R
> install.packages("XML")
trying URL 'https://cran.uni-muenster.de/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.20.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1600829 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/dg/hbvl43fn0b7flfk6l__3bwth0000gq/T/Rtmplh4pEL/R.INSTALL12b2d7b634136/XML':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/Users/dgarfield/miniconda3/envs/r_env/lib/R/library/XML’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/dg/hbvl43fn0b7flfk6l__3bwth0000gq/T/RtmpaiTLe8/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
```

This works perfectly fine on a standard (non-Conda) installation. My guess is that the culprit is this new clang.

Following what I have seen elsewhere, I have tried this with
CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
and
CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=/opt/MacOSX10.9.sdk

So it doesn't seem to be anything too weird with the headers (??). But I'm out of ideas and could use some guidance.

(and yes, I know that in the case of XML, conda could to the install for me, but that isn't the case for all packages).

Thanks!

Comment: You’re not the first one to experience trouble with R installations under Conda. I don’t know why the Conda R package provides its own clang, and how this messes stuff up but there seem to be pervasive issues when mixing Conda R packages with “manual” R package installation. My recommendation is to either *only* use Conda ([`conda install r-xml`](https://anaconda.org/r/r-xml)), or to drop Conda for R.

Comment: It seems to be fairly specific to MacOS, as this trick (mostly) worked well on our server. But yes, it is frustrating and your suggestion seems to be the best one so far....